# Function create with sqldf in R

Tags: r

I am trying to format my data to be able to create a time series with ggplot, which I am doing via sqldf:

```
groups <- sample(c("A","B","C"),20, replace = TRUE)
date <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 20)
df <- data.frame(set = groups, date = as.Date(date))

   set       date
1    A 1999-09-01
2    B 1999-02-04
3    B 1999-05-20
4    B 1999-04-10
5    A 1999-10-22
6    A 1999-06-11
7    A 1999-10-19
8    B 1999-12-26
9    A 1999-10-12
10   C 1999-06-07
11   A 1999-09-26
12   B 1999-08-12
13   C 1999-09-09
14   A 1999-01-01
15   B 1999-06-17
16   A 1999-03-19
17   A 1999-05-13
18   C 1999-08-02
19   C 1999-05-03
20   B 1999-02-08

create_group_time_series <- function(date, category){
  data_tm <- sqldf(paste("SELECT", date, category, "COUNT(*) as Freq FROM df GROUP BY", date, category,"ORDER BY", category, date, sep=" "))
  return(data_tm)  
}
create_group_time_series(df$date, df$set)
```

This returns:

```
 Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: near "COUNT": syntax error
```

This query works on its own when its not encapsulated by a function. date and category are set to be columns of `data` of equal length.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: How about a sample data set?

Comment: Naming a dataset 'data' is a particularly bad idea when calling for it to be identified outside a function to which you have not passed it. (It's also the name of an R function, although it's not clear that is the cause of the problem.)

Comment: The way your function is set up, you want the arguments to be column names, e.g. `"date"` and `"set"`. But you are passing *vectors*, e.g. `df$date` and `df$set`. Also you're missing commas as pointed out in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments we want to insert the **names** of the columns into the SQL string -- not the columns themselves.   I have added a `set.seed` to make the input reproducible.

```
library(sqldf)
set.seed(123)
groups <- sample(c("A","B","C"),20, replace = TRUE)
date <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 20)
df <- data.frame(set = groups, date = as.Date(date))

create_group_time_series <- function(date, category) {
   fn$sqldf('SELECT "$date", "$category", COUNT(*) as Freq 
             FROM df 
             GROUP BY "$date", "$category"
             ORDER BY "$category", "$date"')
}

g <- create_group_time_series("date", "set")
```

Note that the number of substitutions could be reduced like this:

```
create_group_time_series2 <- function(date, category) {
   fn$sqldf('SELECT "$date", "$category", COUNT(*) as Freq 
             FROM df 
             GROUP BY 1, 2
             ORDER BY 2, 1')
}

g2 <- create_group_time_series2("date", "set")

identical(g, g2) # TRUE
```

**Added**

Note that it would be better if we passed the data frame as well as the column names since otherwise the data frame is a free variable and the function will be at the mercy of R's scoping rules to find it.  Also, it is common in R to pass a formula with a data frame when it is desired to pass column names, e.g. `plot(y ~ x, DF)`, `lm(y ~ x, DF)`. To implement that approach let us agree that the date must be the first variable in the formula.  Then:

```
create_group_time_series3 <- function(formula, data) {
   v <- all.vars(formula)
   fn$sqldf('SELECT "`v[1]`", "`v[2]`", COUNT(*) as Freq 
             FROM "data" 
             GROUP BY 1, 2
             ORDER BY 2, 1')
}

g3 <- create_group_time_series3(~ date + set, df)

identical(g, g3) # TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma before the count.

Also, you need a comma between date and category in your paste().

Also in your group by and order by.

```
create_group_time_series <- function(date, category){
  data_tm <- sqldf(paste("SELECT", date, ",", category, ",COUNT(*) as Freq FROM df GROUP BY", date, "," , category,"ORDER BY", category, ",", date, sep=" "))
  return(data_tm)  
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't there need to be commas in the `Group By` and `Order By` clauses too?

Comment: Yup, just realized those were missing and edited my answer.

Comment: Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such column: A

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @G.Grothendieck is of course the correct one but there's a nuance here that's worth pointing out (IMHO). Notice how the column names were put in double quotes:

```
query <- 'SELECT "date", "set", count(*) as Freq FROM df GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 2,1'
result <- sqldf(query)
```

Omitting the quotes would not have worked:

```
query <- 'SELECT date, set, count(*) as Freq FROM df GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 2,1'
result <- sqldf(query)
# Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : error in statement: near "set": syntax error
```

This is because you are using a reserved word ("set") as a column name. If you had named the "set" column something else, you would not need the quotes.

```
df    <- data.frame(grp= groups, date = as.Date(date))
query <- 'SELECT date, grp , count(*) as Freq FROM df GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 2,1'
result <- sqldf(query)
```

I suppose the object lesson is to always put column names in double quotes when using sqldf.